# Distribute equitative random

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to do this...

I have some activities and I need to distribute it (900 activities on 15 persons) but it must to be equitative random, i found a way to distribute randomly but it doesn't equitative.

The formula than I used

```
=INDEX(A2:A16,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A2:A16))
```

and the result aren't equitative

```
person 1    93
person 2    86
person 3    86
person 4    93
person 5    100
person 6    115
person 7    111
person 8    48
person 9    42
person 10   34
person 11   42
person 12   60
```

There is a way to do it more equitative because for example the person 7 has a lot more of activities than de person 10?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim cell As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = 1 To 900
        Set cell = Range("B" & wf.RandBetween(1, 15))
        cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Typical result:

[image]

The process is to:

1. pick a cell between **B1** and **B15** at random
2. increment the cell's value by one

The process is repeated 900 times.

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Can explain how to make it work?
I didn't understand

Comment: @Dragonel  See my **EDIT#1**